# get with curl from itunes api

Tags: php, api, curl, itunes

first off all Happy New Year.
So, my question is : how to get with cURL from itunes api?
here is my old example with `file_get_contents`, but it returns 403 forbidden.
Down is a my old code

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term='.$iartist.'&limit=1&media=music&entity=song');
$response = json_decode($data); 
    if ($response->results==NULL){
    echo '';    
    }else{
    foreach ($response->results as $result)
$result->artworkUrl100 = preg_replace('/100x100bb.jpg/ms', "450x450bb.jpg", $result->artworkUrl100);
    {}
```

so, i want to change this code with cURL

Comment: Why do you need to change it to `curl` if `file_get_contents` works?

Comment: we are not just going to translate you code to curl for you

Comment: file_get_contents not working!